# Start Activity on Receiving SMS

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sms

I want to run **ActivityIwanttoRun.class** `Activity` on receiving sms which contains **"Run activity"**.. the if statement is working as it Toast a message when a sms receive containing text **"RunActivity"**.

But it does not show Toast "You have called your second activity" statement in **ActivityIwanttoRun.class** --

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here.. I just want to see my Activity - "**ActivityIwanttoRun**" run on receiving sms.

**IncomingSms.java**

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver  {

final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    if(message.contains("RunActivity")) {

                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context,ActivityIwanttoRun.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent2);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}
```

}

**ActivityIwanttoRun.java**

```
public class ActivityIwanttoRun extends Activity  {
private static final String TAG = "ActivityIwanttoRun";

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    updateUI();
}

 private void updateUI() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "You have called your second activity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

}
```

}

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ActivityIwanttoRun">

    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Add some `LogCat` prints in `ActivityIWanttoRun`, to pinpoint the problem - add one in the `onCreate` (`Log.d("TAG", "onCreate")`) and another one just before the `Toast` - `Log.d("TAG", "Toast")`. That way you can tell if the second `Activity` actually runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of All you are launching **LocationActivity** instead of  **ActivityIwanttoRun**

change

```
 Intent intent2 = new Intent(context,LocationActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent2);
```

to

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(context,ActivityIwanttoRun.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent2);
```

Correct way to call `Activity` from `BroadcastReceiver` is

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(context,ActivityIwanttoRun.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent2);
intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent2);
```

Comment: try to set full package name for activity in intent

Comment: @ Nilesh Jarad it worked on android 2.3.3 but it did not worked on 5.1.1

Comment: try to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>` in manifest

Comment: But I have added all permissions in my real project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83626/discussion-between-tp-ap-and-nilesh-jarad).

Answer (score 1):

Use this

Intent in = new Intent();

```
    in.setClassName("package name", "package name.ActivityIwanttoRun");

    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    context.startActivity(in);
```

and mention internet and receive sms permission as child of manifest